# multipal connection using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Am using JMETER from past few days,What happened is m used HTTP Request defaults there i mentioned testing server domain name of my server And in HTTP Request m used exact path of testing webapp.after giving lots of load to server my server has been crashed all data in server has been erased. after checking server logs.its displaying user name , pwd is wrong..
After that i testing in LOCALHOST there also after giving lot of load.SQL is displaying too many connections.... can anyone help me how to use JMETER in proper way. its opening new connection for every thread with out closing old one..

Comment: connections to Database are made via Webapp. so if the connections are not getting closed you need to check your webapp code.

Comment: Make sure you have as many DB connections as your server host (apache?) has. Make sure they are closed by the server when done.