# How to identify number of connections establishing and closing in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Are we able to know, when the connection was established and/or closed in each thread loop?

Actually I tried before I was  working in localhost, there it displayed that in database too many connections established.

Was that a Jmeter setting problem or a webapp coding problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [multipal connection using jmeter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602087/multipal-connection-using-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following points below to determine the issue, possibly it is a Webapp configuration/code issue:

- Check if the DB connections remain open even after the jmeter test has stopped.
- Use netstat command on your app server to check the open http connections.
- debug your webapp code to verify DB connections are getting closed.

Hope this will help.

Comment: In local DB we can check the connections opened or closed.
How to check in server when its deployed, What happened is 1st time i started check in server by providing loop forever, My domain server has been crashed.
After checking my server logs, There for every loop it was asking DOMAIN user name and pwd What will be the Problem ?

Comment: In the server where it is deployed, the infrastructure team server admin/DBA should do it. for your second question: please clarify, is your jmeter script working fine with single user? have you verified the responses in "view tree listener"?  if both are correct, then your server is not able to handle the user load you are hitting it with.